# Comment conventions in python

Tags: python, comments

It seems like you can use both `'''comments...'''` and `"""comments..."""` for multi-line comments.  Is there any substantive difference between the two, or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are not comments, they are [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Python allows you to define multi-line strings using triplets of either apostrophes or quotation marks, but PEP 257 recommends using the quotation marks with docstrings for consistency. It has no effect on the contents of the string, however.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of preference. I would say it's more *common* to see double quotes with triple-quoted strings, especially when they're used as docstrings, but there's no functional difference between the two.